# update cloudera quickstart vm to use java7

Tags: java, hadoop, centos, config, cloudera

I'm new to Hadoop and I use the cloudera quickstart vm (Version: Cloudera Standard 4.7.2) to get familiar with Hadoop. I have made a java MRJ compiled to java 1.7, the cloudera vm runs on java 1.6, so I get an “Unsupported major.minor version 51.0” error. The MRJ needs to be java 1.7, therefor my question is, how can I get the cloudera vm to use java 1.7?

I have basic Linux skills (ubuntu), the cloudera vm runs on centos. I have already try'd to find a how to on google. Bud cant find what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera Quickstart CDH 5.3 is now available which runs om java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest 4.x VM from Cloudera, the file name says 4.7 but it actually contained 4.8.3 (at the time of my download):

https://downloads.cloudera.com/demo_vm/vmware/cloudera-quickstart-vm-4.7.0-0-vmware.7z

It contained `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31`. I installed `jdk1.7.0_80` alongside it.
I then tried:

1. changing the symlink `/usr/java/default`
2. editing `/etc/default/bigtop-utils` as per http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_29_1.html
3. moving `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31` somewhere else and then making `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31` a symlink to the new JDK

The last one is a dirty hack but it's the only one that worked for me.
There is probably a better way to do it though : )